# Continuous change of led params RPI from remote access

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I have RPI4 where have attached RGB LED. This led has to blink with certain frequency and color forever. I have such python service:

```
#libraries
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from time import sleep
import os
import schedule
import time

#disable warnings (optional)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
#Select GPIO Mode
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
#set red,green and blue pins
redPin = 12
greenPin = 19
bluePin = 13
isLight = False
#set pins as outputs
GPIO.setup(redPin,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(greenPin,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(bluePin,GPIO.OUT)

def turnOff():
    GPIO.output(redPin,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(greenPin,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(bluePin,GPIO.HIGH)
    
def white():
    GPIO.output(redPin,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(greenPin,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(bluePin,GPIO.LOW)
    
def red():
    GPIO.output(redPin,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(greenPin,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(bluePin,GPIO.HIGH)

def green():
    GPIO.output(redPin,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(greenPin,GPIO.LOW)
    GPIO.output(bluePin,GPIO.HIGH)
    
def blue():
    GPIO.output(redPin,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(greenPin,GPIO.HIGH)
    GPIO.output(bluePin,GPIO.LOW)
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    turnOff()
    isLight = False
    
    while True:
        led_info = os.getenv('LED_INFO')

        print(os.environ)
        color = led_info[-1]
        frequency = led_info[:-1]
        time.sleep(int(frequency) / 1000)
        if isLight:
            isLight = False
            turnOff()
        else:
            isLight = True
            if color == 'R':
                red()
            elif color == 'G':
                green()
            elif color == 'B':
                blue()
```

as you can see here I get info from environmental variable and apply it in the loop. But what I'm trying to make is to change frequency of blinking and color in runtime. For example from mobile device. I don't understand which solution will be better:

- open socket connection
- open ssh connection

in both of these solutions I will then (as I understood) edit environmental variable which will be then used in the loop. The problem of such solution is that when I'm changing smth in runtime I get exception which says that this variable is broken. Then I thought about local project configurational file via `dotenv` for example, but not sure that I'm really on the right way.

### update

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os
import time
from time import sleep
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import schedule

host_name = ''  # Change this to your Raspberry Pi IP address
host_port = 8000

# GPIO setup
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
# set red,green and blue pins
redPin = 12
greenPin = 19
bluePin = 13
# set pins as outputs
GPIO.setup(redPin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(greenPin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(bluePin, GPIO.OUT)


class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    isLight = False
    """ A special implementation of BaseHTTPRequestHander for reading data from
        and control GPIO of a Raspberry Pi
    """

    def do_HEAD(self):
        """ do_HEAD() can be tested use curl command
            'curl -I http://server-ip-address:port'
        """
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def _redirect(self, path):
        self.send_response(303)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.send_header('Location', path)
        self.end_headers()

    def turnOff(self):
        GPIO.output(redPin, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(greenPin, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(bluePin, GPIO.HIGH)

    def white(self):
        GPIO.output(redPin, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(greenPin, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(bluePin, GPIO.LOW)

    def red(self):
        GPIO.output(redPin, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(greenPin, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(bluePin, GPIO.HIGH)

    def green(self):
        GPIO.output(redPin, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(greenPin, GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(bluePin, GPIO.HIGH)

    def blue(self):
        GPIO.output(redPin, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(greenPin, GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(bluePin, GPIO.LOW)
        
    def runLoop(self, color, frequency):
        while True:
            time.sleep(int(frequency) / 1000)
            if self.isLight:
                self.isLight = False
                self.turnOff()
            else:
                self.isLight = True
                if color == 'R':
                    self.red()
                elif color == 'G':
                    self.green()
                elif color == 'B':
                    self.blue()

    def do_GET(self):
        """ do_GET() can be tested using curl command
            'curl http://server-ip-address:port'
        """
        html = '''
           <html>
           <body style="width:960px; margin: 20px auto;">
           <h1>Welcome to my Raspberry Pi</h1>
           <p>Current GPU temperature is {}</p>
           <form action="/" method="POST">
               Turn LED :
               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="On">
               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Off">
               <input type="text" name="submit">
           </form>
           </body>
           </html>
        '''
        temp = os.popen("/opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp").read()
        self.do_HEAD()
        self.wfile.write(html.format(temp[5:]).encode("utf-8"))

    def do_POST(self):
        """ do_POST() can be tested using curl command
            'curl -d "submit=On" http://server-ip-address:port'
        """
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])  # Get the size of data
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length).decode("utf-8")  # Get the data

        post_data = post_data.split("=")[1]  # Only keep the valu

        color = post_data[-1]
        frequency = post_data[:-1]

        self.runLoop(color, frequency)
        print("LED is {}".format(post_data))
        self._redirect('/')  # Redirect back to the root url


if __name__ == '__main__':
    http_server = HTTPServer((host_name, host_port), MyServer)
    print("Server Starts - %s:%s" % (host_name, host_port))

    try:
        http_server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        http_server.server_close()
```

here I can pass value for color/blinking only one time and then all stuck

Comment: Why not run a Python simple HTTP server on the RasPi? Then you don’t need any software other than a standard web browser on your remote devices.

Comment: I have nginx at this moment, not sure whether it is `simple` http server)) but I have here api for example. and of course I don't fully understand how to achieve such solution with server :(

Comment: You don’t need nginx or apache or lighttpd, Python has a built-in, stand-alone  http server https://www.e-tinkers.com/2018/04/how-to-control-raspberry-pi-gpio-via-http-web-server/

Comment: hm... thank you for this direction, and how fast is it? I mean that if I click on button every 1 second for changing frequency, so will it have some delay or not? I thought about changing env_var directly for preventing some possible delays

Comment: I don't think your env_var method is going to work too well anyway... external processes cannot change another process's environment variables. It will be very quick clicking buttons - try it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, yes, finally I figured out what you mean, but in the new edition of my question I can only one time set of frequency/color and then I can't do it, maybe loop usage is not idea, but when I tried to set it in the POST method I saw that it can not be set at all, maybe you can see the problem?

Comment: You can't start running an endless loop inside your POST endpoint - else you'll never finish answering the POST and you'll never look for other button clicks or POSTs. If you want to do something else, like run loops, you'll want to start a separate thread that does that independently. Then you can send it messages using a threading queue to tell it to stop and start things.

Comment: yes, I got it finally, thank you for your help

Comment: Cool - sorry I didn't have time to code it up for you. It'll be great if you wanted to post it as an answer for others to get some ideas from. Good luck with your project.

Comment: sometimes it is good when somebody does not have time for coding) in such case we code alone with own brain :D and yes sure, I will post the solution soon, I need to polish it little bit. Thank you and have a nice day!